# Combining cells with same color into one column

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with multiple columns that have data with the cells filled with different colors.

I am trying to figure out how to combine the like filled color cells into separate columns on a separate sheet. (all of the red filled cells on one column, the blue in the next column, ect.)

**The cells are manually color coded

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RbUE.png]

Comment: How do you color the cells? Manually or by conditional formatting? If you do it by CF then you can use same formula to filter data. If you do it manually then you need VBA macro.

Comment: The best way to handle such a case is by starting with the criteria which causes the colours.